# Force page to refresh state when you return to it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am using Nuxt in SPA mode and have a page structure like this:

```
pages

...

- users/
- - index
- - new
- - update/
- - - _id

...
```

I have a page of users with a list of them and 'subpage' - new.

On my `users/index` page I am fetching my users in asyncData Hook like this:

```
async asyncData({ app: { apolloProvider }, store: { commit, dispatch } }) {
    
    const {
      data: { getAllUsers: { success, users, message } },
    } = await apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
      query: getAllUsersGQL,
    })

    if(success) {
      await commit('user/setUsers', users, { root: true })
    } else {
      dispatch('snackbar/notify', { message: message, type: 'error' }, { root: true })
    }

  },
```

It seems to work as it should. But when I go to my page `users/new`, fill up the form and send it, update the store and redirect to my `users/index` page, I encounter kinda interesting behaviour.

The problem here is that I don't have a newly updated state but some kinda cached one or previous state. I can so far make it working with `location.replace`. When the page reloads I have an accurate and updated state.

That's how I'm handling redirect on `users/new` page:

```
    async save() {

      if(this.$refs.create.validate()) {
        this.loading = true
          
        delete this.form.confirm

        await this.createUserStore(this.form)

        this.$router.push(
          this.localeLocation({
            name: 'users',
          })
        )

        this.loading = false
        this.$refs.create.reset()
      }
    },
```

and that's how I am refreshing my state in Vuex:

```
export const mutations = {
    updateUsers: (state, payload) => {
        state.users = [...state.users, payload].sort((a,b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
    },
}
```

That's how I'm passing data:

```
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            storeUsers: 'user/getUsers',
            storeGetMe: 'auth/getMe',
        }),
    },
```

```html
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="storeUsers"
    :search="search"
    item-key="id"
    class="elevation-1"
    dense
>
</v-data-table>
```

I already tried to list items using v-for and it doesn't work either.
And when I console.log state I get all items. It works as it should.

What can be the problem that it's not updating the view?

If anyone has ever faced such kind of behaviour I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: What do you mean by a previous state? If your page makes an AJAX request onload and you redirect to it, of course it will execute again onload.

Comment: @StackSlave yes, the hook asyncData triggers (I just in case checked it) but when I return to the previous page I don’t see the updated list of users. I can see the list I saw before sending out the form

Comment: Even if the AJAX call was made from the same webpage, data would not be shared between Server pages without the use of a Server session or database query, unless you are sending data from the Client that you received back to the same page that you resend to the Server *(not ideal)*.

Comment: @StackSlave sorry  but I can’t get what you mean here. It should work like this: I’m sending the form, redirect to the previous page. The previous page has got a hook and retrieves updated list and updates the store do I can see the updated list of users. At what step in that chain is the problem?

Comment: Looks like a reactivity issue to me.  Try removing the `.sort`, logging the length of the array, and creating a user.  If the length changes, add the sort and let us know if that is the issue.

Comment: @HMilbradt tried it. Removing .sort doesn’t help. When I check the store on reload everything is fine. I checked that too. It just kinda cache previous state in the presentation component. Maybe the issue is somewhere in the Vuetify component v-data-table. Or something else 

Comment: @HMilbradt interesting that when I delete a user (on that same page) and update the state it reacts as it should. It works but only when I return to the page the issue pops up

Comment: How are you accessing the state on your user index page?  It's possible that you're updating the array in a reactive way, but not accessing it in a reactive way.  These kinds of issues tend to do exactly what you're describing.

Comment: It might help to drop a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox as well

Comment: @HMilbradt using mapGetters. Déstructure properties into my computed section. Passing that computed property to the table component :items=“users”

Comment: @HMilbradt yeah, maybe if I can’t solve it tomorrow morning I’ll provide codesandbox. Played around with that fo hours today ‍♂️ thanks for being nearby by the way

Comment: @HMilbradt updated my question with the way I'm passing props to the table component. Have any ideas on why it's happening?

Comment: @midnight_dev I still don't see what it could be from this.  I'd highly recommend putting up a minimal reproducible example.  For the record, I doubt it's the table component since Vuetify is such a big and well maintained library.

Comment: @HMilbradt yes, it's not Vuetify because I tried without it. Weird, very weird behavior. But thanks anyway

Comment: @HMilbradt, if you don't mind I've got a question concerning DevOps. I'm planning to put the architecture on microservices and deploy it using Kubernetes. But it seems a bit more expensive to deploy apps on EKS (AWS). Could you tell me what's the avarage cost to deploy Kuberbetes architecture (let's say two instances per app - 3 apps = 6 instances total). Because I heard it's kinda too expensive on EKS)

Comment: I believe it's ~$80/cluster/month, then you need to bring your own EC2 and fargate instances on top of that.  Managed services are always more expensive, with the tradeoff being your own time, energy, and expertise.  Note that they're also usually much less flexible.  I'd recommend opening a new question specific to this, as I only have experience with ECS

Comment: @HMilbradt Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably coming from the fact that Apollo does have it's [own cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#supported-fetch-policies) and that it reaches for the cache first as `cache-first` is the default value.

Give this one a try

```js
await apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
  query: getAllUsersGQL,
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
})
```

---

#### Additional answer

This is an example of a dynamic GQL query that I previously wrote

`test.gql.js`

```js
import { gql } from 'graphql-tag'
import { constantCase, pascalCase } from 'change-case'

export const queryCompanyBenefitInfo = ({
  benefitType,
  needCifEligibility = false,
  needActiveOnWeekend = false,
  needCompanyContribution = false,
  needAutoRenewed = false,
  needUnitValue = false,
}) => {
  return gql`
    query {
      CompanyBenefit {
        oneOfType(benefitType: ${constantCase(benefitType)}) {
          ... on Company${pascalCase(benefitType)}Benefit {
            ${needCifEligibility ? 'cifEligibility' : ''}
            ${needActiveOnWeekend ? 'activeOnWeekend' : ''}
            ${needCompanyContribution ? 'companyContribution' : ''}
            ${needAutoRenewed ? 'autoRenewed' : ''}

            ${
              needUnitValue
                ? `unitValue {
                    value
                  }`
                : ''
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `
}
```

And call it this way

```js
import { testQuery } from '~/apollo/queries/test.gql.js'

...

await this.app.apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
  query: testQuery({ benefitType: 'care', needCifEligibility: true }),
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
  errorPolicy: 'all',
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right. It was the issue here and your solution fixes it well!

Comment: @midnight_dev this is a nuke tho! In some cases, you may wish to still keep the Apollo cache. Meanwhile, from a lot of time spent digging into github issue, Apollo still has some bugs here and there hence why I opted for this solution in my former project. Glad it works tho!

Comment: if you don't mind I've got another question. Maybe you know what's the better way to solve it. I've got on one mutation path a few input types possible. But I cannot use unions with input types, but only with Object types. How can I solve it in GraphQL?

Comment: @midnight_dev I didn't dig that far into what's possible with Apollo. But if something is not doable, you can always import a `.js` file rather than a `.gql` one and use `graphql-tag` to interpolate your query based on conditional options like the way it is demonstrated here: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query (but with params passed to the `.js` file) Tried it myself, working well!

Comment: interesting solution. Thanks again!

Comment: @midnight_dev I've edited my answer to show some raw example!